# Autoit anti-idle script after screen lock

Tags: windows, autoit

I'm trying to make an simple anti-idle script (that moves the mouse or whatever) to prevent an application from stopping.

How can I keep it running after screen lock ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like this is explained in the Autoit faq :
http://www.autoitscript.com/wiki/FAQ#Why_doesn.27t_my_script_work_on_a_locked_workstation.3F

> On locked station any window will never be active (active is only dialog with text "Press Ctrl+Alt+Del") In Windows locked state applications runs hidden (behind that visible dialog) and haven't focus and active status.
>
> So generally don't use **Send() MouseClick() WinActivate() WinWaitActive() WinActive()** etc.
>
> Instead use **ControlSend() ControlSetText() ControlClick() WinWait() WinExists() WinMenuSelectItem()** etc. This way you may have your script resistive against another active windows. It's possible to run such script from scheduler on locked Windows station.

Answer (score 3):

You can't automate anything after your screen is locked. User input is simply ignored. A much easier way would be to prevent your screen from locking, for example, by moving the mouse randomly every 30 seconds.